# How to use explode() on $_POST

Tags: php

Could somebody please help me with `explode()` function. I am reading values with `$_POST[]` from a form on my web page, which holds 3 values: `$user_id[$nro]".": "."$fname[$nro]".","."$sname[$nro]`.

Now I am trying to explode the `$_POST()` values, but I can not get it to work. I have tried it in 2 different ways, but no luck...

First way:

```
$uservalue = array();
$uservalue = $_POST['userlist'];
foreach($uservalue as $line => $content) {
  $uservalue[$line] = explode(',',$content);
}
print_r($uservalue);
```

There are no values in the new `$uservalue[]`.

Second way:

```
$uservalue = $_POST['userlist'];
$uservalue = explode(":", $uservalue);
$uservalue = explode(",", $uservalue);

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in ...
```

Could somebody please help me and tell how to do it properly?

Thanks.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: And what does your `$_POST` contain exactly?

Comment: The $_POST: 1: kevin,costner For example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you echo the form value on the page, you have redundant quotes. What you have now is (I assume):

```
echo "$user_id[$nro]".": "."$fname[$nro]".","."$sname[$nro]";
```

While the more appropriate would be:

```
echo $user_id[$nro].": ".$fname[$nro].",".$sname[$nro];
```

I.e., you don't need to double quote the variables.

Second, I assume you are trying to split the `$_POST` variable to its three components. Your approach might be flawed, as you could save those values directly in three different form elements:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id[$nro]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="<?php echo $fname[$nro]; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="sname" value="<?php echo $sname[$nro]; ?>" />
```

And you could then access those variables individually.

But, to answer your question, you can split your string like this:

```
// Added for example, your value comes from $_POST
$str = "1: kevin,costner";

list($user_id, $rest) = explode(": ", $str);
// $user_id is a string, contains "1"
// $rest is a string, contains "kevin,costner"

// Explode the $rest again
list($fname, $sname) = explode(",", $rest);
// $fname is a string, contains "kevin"
// $sname is a string, contains "costner"
```

Now you have three different variables that hold your values.

Also, the nature of this site is to accept answers you found helpful, so please do if you find help here!

Comment: I need the "extra-quotes", because the I am echoing the values  in a form drop menu and I can not split them in 3 different hiddenvalues, because I need to get the info based on users choice on the list. Thank you very much now I got it working. Thanks

Comment: No, actually you don't need the extra quotes, they are redundant. If your code stops working when you take them off, then you have something wrong with the surrounding code. Either way, they are not needed.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to achieve? Also, what does $_POST contain?

If you want the users in an array, your answer is simply this: (no need for a loop)

```
$userList = explode(',', $_POST['userlist']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Explode splits a string based on the separator, and puts it into an array.

In your first example, $uservalue = array(); isn't necessary, as assumedly $_POST['userlist'] is a string, not an array.

Can you post the results of just this code when you have posted something to that page? (i.e. just stick this right at the top! You probably want to view source to copy and paste it, as it won't look nice on a rendered page)

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

OK, looking at what you are doing (Not sure why you are putting it all into one variable, rather than seperate ones btw!) you could do:

```
$userlist = $_POST['userlist'];
$explode_on_colon = explode(":",$userlist);
$uservalue[0] = $explode_on_colon[0];

$explode_on_comma = explode(",", $explode_on_colon)

$uservalue[1] = $explode_on_comma[0];
$uservalue[2] = $explode_on_comma[1];
```

I haven't tried that, but you get the idea. You can't do `explode(",", $explode_on_colon)[0]` in PHP unfortunately, hence the temporary variables.

Comment: the print_r($_POST) value is: 1: kevin,costner after I have exploded I would need it in something like this $uservalue[0] = 1 $uservalue[1] = kevin $uservalue[2] = costner

Answer (score 0):

Just Happened to me: 
i was setting all in one line but did not worked

```
$aFromPOST = explode (',',$_POST['cattodel']); 
// $_POST['cattodel'] has this values s,d,e,i
```

I had to place it in two separated lines and worked ...dunno why but it was like this that it worked...

```
 $sPOST= $_POST['cattodel']; // $_POST['cattodel'] has this values s,d,e,i
 $aFromPOST = explode (',',$sPOST);
```